# z3 Solver solution issues

Tags: python, constraints, z3, z3py

```
p = Int('p')
q = Int('q')

s = Solver()
s.add(1<=p<=9, 1<=q<=19, 5<(3*p-4*q)<10)
s.check() 
print s.model()
```

returns sat, and gives the solution

```
[p = 0, q = 0]
```

which does not satisfy the constraints. If I remove the final constraint, it returns 
a sensible pair that satisfies the first two (trivial) constraints. What's going on?

Permalink to try this online: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/fk4

---

EDIT : I'm new to z3, so there's a chance I'm doing something horribly wrong, do let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Z3 does not support using Python's comparison chaining i.e. that `a < b < c` is the same as `a < b and b < c`. Z3 can not be made to support it without overloading `and` which is currently not possible in Python. 
So `a < b < c` should be written as:

```
b_ = b
Z3.And(a < b_, b_ < c)
```

to only evaluate the expression `b` once.

---

After replacing the `s.add` line with:

```
s.add(1<=p, p<=9, 1<=q, q<=19, 5<(3*p-4*q), (3*p-4*q)<10)
```

I get:

```
[p = 6, q = 3]
```

So you have to split them up as I did above for the solver.

---

Python expands `1<=p<=9` to `1<=p and p<=9`, when that is interpreted this results in `p<=9` as `bool(1 <= p)` is `True`, the code in the question results in solving for:

```
s.add(p<=9, q<=19, (3*p-4*q)<10)
```

for which `[p = 0, q = 0]` is one of the solutions.

Comment: Yep, just figured that out as well. It's strange, because their documentation seems to suggest you can.

Comment: Santosh: The Python documentation suggests you can overload `and`, or the Z3 documentation suggests it supports it?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger The documentation for Z3 led @santosh.ankr to think that Z3 supported using Python's comparison chaining i.e. `a<b<c` but this is not supported by Z3, and Z3 can not be made to support it without overloading `and` which is currently not possible in Python. So `a<b<c` must be written as `b_ = b` / `Z3.And(a<b_, b_<c)`